# Footer displays if site has litte/no content, won't remain at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, footer

I currently have a footer that I have at the bottom of a page.  The problem is I don't want it fixed, and I don't want it to sit 100% at the bottom.  But everything I do makes it sticky, site at the bottom hiding the bottom shadow, or sit in the middle of the page.  If the site has content, the footer is fine, but if the page has little to no content, the footer rests right where the content ends, instead of the bottom of the page.  I am adding an image of the footer when it's sitting correctly at the bottom of the page.  If the page has no content, this is in the middle of the page.
[image: Footer at bottom of page]

```
footer {
padding: 30px 0;
margin-top: 0;
background: #e9e9e9 url("../Images/noise.jpg") repeat;
border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
font-size: 13px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
```

}

Comment: You'll need to update your question and provide us with a [mcve]. A single CSS rule isn't sufficient.

Comment: if you don't want to make it fixed position, you can try assigning `min-height` to your content element so that footer sits at the bottom even there is no or less content.

Comment: Arya, ty for your response.  I have entered this, but the footer continues to ride up the site if there is no content present, 
    .body-content {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

Answer (score 1):

[This blog has your solution](https://chrisbracco.com/css-sticky-footer-effect/)

```css
/**
 * Demo Styles
 */

html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.demo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 64px;
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 94%;
}

.demo h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

/**
 * Footer Styles
 */

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <h1>CSS “Always on the bottom” Footer</h1>

  <p>I often find myself designing a website where the footer must rest at the bottom of the page, even if the content above it is too short to push it to the bottom of the viewport naturally.</p>

  <p>However, if the content is taller than the user’s viewport, then the footer should disappear from view as it would normally, resting at the bottom of the page (not fixed to the viewport).</p>

  <p>If you know the height of the footer, then you should set it explicitly, and set the bottom padding of the footer’s parent element to be the same value (or larger if you want some spacing).</p>

  <p>This is to prevent the footer from overlapping the content above it, since it is being removed from the document flow with <code>position: absolute;</code>.</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>.</div>
```

Another solution could be to have a min-height but that is possible only if you have a fixed height footer.

So you can create a layout like this:

```css
.content {
  min-height: calc( 100vh - 80px )
}
.footer {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
 small or no content here
</div>
<div class="footer">
 footer here
</div>
```